# Unity, how to receive the quantity of the collisions with my collider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity3d: how to receive the number of the collisions with my collider after setting the position of the game object with this collider?

I have tried to do it like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GettingQuantityOfCollisions : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int QuantityOfTheObjectsInTheZone = 0;
    public int GetQuantityOfTheObjectsInTheZone() => QuantityOfTheObjectsInTheZone;

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision anyCollision) => QuantityOfTheObjectsInTheZone++;
    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision anyCollision) => QuantityOfTheObjectsInTheZone--;
}
```

But it does not work when I set the transform.position of the game object with the collider directly.

Comment: may be this is help. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-contactCount.html
But if your code doesn't work, double check that you've put a Rigidbody and not a Collision into one of the components that collide with each other.

Comment: You must use forces to move the object , setting the transform will have that effect.

Comment: Moving anything with `transform.position` will took that object out of physics engine and may not consider the collision, also double check one of your gameobject also have `Rigidbody` attached.